# how to get network connection type without using READ_PHONE_STATE permission in android 10?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

One of the things android 10 is changing is that we cannot get READ_PHONE_STATE automatically,
And have to direct the user to manually give the permission by going to app info > permissions > phone > turn on.

is there any way to get network state (if the phone is on wifi / 3g, etc) on android 10 and above
Without directing the user to go to the application settings by himself and change the permission manually?

I was thinking to bypass the permission asking with

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkCapabilities caps = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActivityNetwork());
boolean isMobile = caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
boolean isWifi = caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
```

would that be ok and then not needed to use the READ_PHONE_STATE permission ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a class `NetworkInfo` it have a function
`getTypeName()` that return string value contain `MOBILE` or `WIFI`

I try to write function I hope it will be helpful for you :

```
    /**
     * @param mType : type of network connection "MOBILE" or "WIFI"
     * @return : true of false
     */
    public boolean isMyType(String mType) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        //
        if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return activeNetworkInfo.getTypeName().equals(mType);
        } else {
            // no internet connection
            return false;
        }
    }
```

than you can call it :

```
  boolean isMobile = isMyType("MOBILE");
  boolean isWifi = isMyType("WIFI");

  // for logcat debug
  Log.i("typeNetwork", "is mobile :" + isMobile);
  Log.i("typeNetwork", "is wifi :" + isWifi);
```

let me know if this works for you..

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version to the above answer -

```
val connectivityManager =
            context?.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
        val activeNetworkInfo: NetworkInfo? = connectivityManager?.activeNetworkInfo

        if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected) {
            return if (activeNetworkInfo.typeName.equals("WIFI")) {
                Log.d("prattham", "getNetworkSpeed: -> activeNetworkInfo is WIFI ")

            } else if (activeNetworkInfo.typeName.equals("MOBILE")) {
               

            }else{
               

            }
        } else {
            // no internet connection
          
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).